# Python Compare sorting for different data types

Tags: python, sorting, theory

Python. I trying to find any information for sorting different data types. For example: 'what type of data will be sorted faster: list or dictionary?' or 'what type of data will be sorted faster: list, dictionary, tuple or set?' and why?
Maybe is it wrong question?
I would like to get direction where can I read about my issue.
I tried to google it but got nothing.

**I looking for any theoretical information**

Comment: Can you even sort dictionaries, tuples, or sets? Dictionaries and sets in python are unordered as far as I know and tuples are immutable (though I guess a sort could return a new tuple).

Comment: We can sort  dictionaries  by keys or values. We can sort tuples they are just immutable.For sets: if we use `sort` for set we will get sorted list/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of data does not impact the sorting speed, at least not directly. What "*may*" change with the datatype is the time to access or modify the data. But even then it is situational as there is no "one best datatype".

Some data is mutable. It means that it can be modified, such as lists.

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4]
my_list[2] = 6
# Prints: [1,2,6,4]
print(my_list)
```

But other types are immutable, which means they can not be changed. This is the case for tuples.

```
my_tuple = (1,2,3,4)
#Throws: TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
my_tuple[2] = 6
print(my_tuple)
```

So to modify an immutable you must copy everything and put your new numbers in memory (NB. Immutables are great in many situations, but that's for another day). So using only tuples for your sorting algorithm may not be a great idea.

NOW ! ...

What really makes a big difference when sorting is the sorting algorithm. **The sorting algorithm may use a mix of mutable and immutable data types** for the sake of optimization but that's not what you should focus on. At the end of the day, you should learn how sorting algorithms work first before trying to optimize them. You should learn what we call, in computer science, the "Big  O notation", which evaluates the complexity of an algorithm.

So to get good with sorting algorithm I advise you the following links:

- [Example of sorting algorithms you could try to implement to git gud](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZZuD6iUe3Pc&ab_channel=ViktorBohush)
- [To learn about mutable and immutables](https://medium.com/@meghamohan/mutable-and-immutable-side-of-python-c2145cf72747)
- [To learn about the Big O notation](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/big-o-time-complexity-what-it-is-and-why-it-matters-for-your-code-6c08dd97ad59)

Then, when you know how algorithms work, you may want to delve into the belly of Python. You can use *timeit* to evaluate "the access time" of each data types and try to get that tiny little bit more sorting power in Python... But **don't do that sort of algorithmic optimization in Python**, that's a trap! Python is great for quickly developing software that works, but Python is slow. If you want **RAW POWER**, implement the algorithm in C or C++ then extend those files to Python, [here is how to do it](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I once asked this question myself. Then I decided to calculate execution time for program. You to calculate the execution time & find yourself which is best!!!

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
main()
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: If dont helps, Please don't unlike. If you need anything please comment~~Thanks

Comment: I already thought about measuring time, but I would like to read some articles with explanations. (I did not unlike your post)